# NuGet Package restore failed: Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll used by another process

Tags: nuget-package-restore

> NuGet Package restore failed for project MyProject.Application: The
>   process cannot access the file
>   'C:\MySolution\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build/Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll'
>   because it is being used by another process..

Any idea how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Windows Explorer went to the folder where the NuGet packages are installed for my solution

```
<VS Solution>\packages\
```

and deleted all the Microsoft.Bcl.* folders. 
After that could rebuild the solution without problems.

Comment: Generally removing packages that appear in error helps. I had problem with Microsoft.Net.Compilers

Comment: Killing msbuild.exe process is easy than deleting all NuGet packages in cases there are lots of packages needs to download.

Answer (score 15):

Find msbuild.exe in process explorer and kill it.

Comment: and kill devenv.exe

Comment: ...and VBCSCompiler.exe

Answer (score 1):

Try running this from an elevated command prompt:

taskkill /im devenv.exe

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem has occured after i installed an update for visual studio components.

As an option, you can try to uninstall Nuget plugin from Visual Studio, and install again (in Tools -> Extensions and Updates).

After that the problematic package successfully restored.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio seems to work - its seems to happen if you have multiple copies of VS open at some point - close all copies and it seems to fix it - for me its always Newtonsoft.json 11.0.2 that causes the issue for some reason. Also ending task on any MSBuild processes.

If you clear the NuGet cache (or delete the .nuget\packages folder the problem does not go away, which suggests the lock is happening during the restore process.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your .csproj file. If you find tags "PropertyGroup" and "ErrorText" with contents like:

### "This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}."

you can safely delete these lines and store the altered .csproj file. Then you should be able to rebuild your project. This worked for me in several cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was having lots of those while trying to restore nuget packages in the solution located on network drive. Just moving it to a local disk helped immediately

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio and kill all msbuild.exe instances, Then delete Microsoft.Bcl* folders from packages folder.